# How to inject Response object to Symfony service during authentication

Tags: php, symfony, cookies, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am writing Symfony Cookie based Authenticator. After getting response from configured UserProvider (remote service call) I would need to set  cookie in the final Response. I don't know how can I access Response object to add new Cookie to it's headers at this stage.

The code for adding a Cookie is normally like this:

```
$cookie = new Cookie('foo', 'bar', strtotime('Wed, 28-Dec-2016 15:00:00 +0100'), '/', '.example.com', true, true, true),
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('foo', 'bar'));
```

I need reference to `$response`

I do not want to create my own instance of Response and return it, since I would like to leave Response creation as it is, but I would only need this one cookie to be added to Response. What is best way to achieve this in Symfony 5?

This is simplified Authenticator code I am using:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;

class SessionCookieAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        // check if php-sid cookie is provided
        return !empty($request->cookies->get('php-sid'));
    }

    /**
     * Credentials are global cookies
     * @param Request $request
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $cookie = implode('; ', array_map(
            function($k, $v) {
                return $k . '=' . $v;
            },
            array_keys($_COOKIE),
            $_COOKIE
        ));
        return $cookie;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {

        return $userProvider->loadUserByCookie($credentials);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return null; // @todo set Cookie here for example. Can I get Response here?
    }

}
```

Comment: The response object does not exist until something creates it along the way.  Typically a controller action.  You can setup a [Kernel Response Subscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#after-filters-with-the-kernel-response-event) which will be called near the end of the request/response processing after the response object is created and add your cookie there.

Comment: That seems logical, but is it possible to pass data via event from UserProvider to Response Subscriber? I now have access to Response but I don't quite understand how can I pass my custom data and retrieve it in event subscriber which has access to Response object.

Comment: As mentioned before, UserProvider seems a strange place for setting a cookie but that is a bit off topic.  However, you can have pretty much any class (including UserProvider) implement EventSubscriber and listen for the Response.  Alternatively, you could indeed have UserProvider emit a custom event and then have your Response subscriber subscribe to it as well as the kernel response event.  Just dive in and mess around a bit until you see the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

`UserProvider` should not set a Cookie, because the Cookie has nothing to do with providing a User. I would suggest to set the Cookie elsewhere (for instance, creating an event listener for `security.authentication.success` or directly inside your Authenticator.

Edit

`onAuthenticationSuccess` lets you return a `Response` (you, basically, need to create it). Upon that response, you can set the needed cookie.

Comment: That is a valid point. Could you expand your answer how do I set a Cookie inside Authenticator (how do I get hold of Response object)?

Comment: Can you update your question with Authenticator code?

Comment: I have modified question for clarity. In case I would like to add cookie inside Authenticator (as you suggested) I still don't know if I can access Response object and if it even already created at that time Authenticator is called or not. I guess best approach would be with event listener then?

Comment: I have added it now

Comment: I do not want to create my own Response as stated in original post, because this is part of Api Platform and response is Rest API response. So I only want to set additional Cookie to Response which would be originally returned to keep basic functionality.